# Node.js Socket.io Clustering - How to set max clients per worker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, cluster-computing

I have a 4 core `CPU` with 8 logical processors, which in this code creates 8 workers and 1 master process. How do I put in a max number of `socket.io` clients/connections each `worker` can take?

E.g - If `worker 1` has 10 (limit) connections -> Connect client to `worker 2`

Node.js Clustering Code

```
const os = require('os'),
  cluster = require('cluster'),
  cores = os.cpus();
var clusterCount = 0;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);
  // Fork workers
  for (let i = 0; i < cores.length; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
}
else {
  const http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    socketio = require('socket.io'),
    process = require('process');;

  var cpu = cores[clusterCount];
  var app = express();
  var port = process.env.PORT || process.argv[2] || 8080;
  var server = app.listen(port);
  var io = socketio(server);

  io.adapter(socketioRedis({ host: config.redis_host, port: config.redis_port }));

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`User ${socket.id} connected to worker ${process.pid}`);
  });

  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started on port: ${port} | ${cpu.model}`);
  clusterCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
var workerConnects = [ ]

//inside your for loop for getting how many cores do:
workerConnects.push(0)    //To set up array for     remembering how many connections each worker has

//Each connection attempt run:
 for(var i = 0; i<workerConnects; i++){
      if(workerConnects[i]<10){
          //connect user to that worker
          workerConnects[i] = workerConnects[i]+1;
           //-1 for disconnect
      }
 }
```

Comment: I think this logic is invalid for this instance, or I may be implementing your example wrong. The clients connect directly to the `io.on` in the worker -- idk where an `if` statement can be implemented pre-connection

Comment: Hmm yeah I might of made a mistake here, I’m doin stuff on my phone:D I’ll look through your code again, and there might be a method for looking at how many clients are connected within Socket.io

Comment: No worries, take your time :) -- there is a method to check how many clients there are, but again, it's done AFTER the connection takes place. Need to route the clients to other workers beforehand, perhaps the routing needs to be done in the `master` process